# inserting an element before and after the elements produced by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Very new to Angular.

I want to emit the following html, where a table has *multiple* `tbody` elements and each `tbody` contains a variable number of detail rows, and the *first* and *final* row of each `tbody` are a special kind of row, a group-header, containing header column names (e.g. **Average Order Amount**) and a group-footer where subtotals and other aggregations like averages and min/max are displayed.

Ideally, when I get it working, I'd like the cells in this aggregation row to point to functions in the model that calculate these aggregate values (subtotals, averages, min, max, etc), passing these functions the class of the tbody in question, e.g. 'west', which the function can use to filter the rows in the dataset.

How would I append these virtual aggregation rows as the final item in each `tbody`?

```
         <tbody class='east'>
             <tr class='group-header-row'>....</tr>

               <tr>...</tr>
               <tr>...</tr>
               <tr>...</tr>
                .
                .
                .
               <tr class='group-footer-row'>....</tr>
         </tbody>

         <tbody class='west'>
                 <tr class='group-header-row'>....</tr>

               <tr>...</tr>
               <tr>...</tr>
               <tr>...</tr>
                .
                .
                .
               <tr class='group-footer-row'>....</tr>
         </tbody>

         <tbody class='north'>
                 <tr class='group-header-row'>....</tr>

               <tr>...</tr>
               <tr>...</tr>
               <tr>...</tr>
                .
                .
                .
               <tr class='group-footer-row'>....</tr>
         </tbody>

         <tbody class='south'>
              <tr class='group-header-row'>....</tr>

               <tr>...</tr>
               <tr>...</tr>
               <tr>...</tr>
                .
                .
                .
               <tr class='group-footer-row'>....</tr>
          </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the special repeat start and end points feature of the ng-repeat directive.  Here's a link to this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<tbody class='north'> //if you have n # of tbody's use a ng-repeat here.  
       <tr class='group-header-row' ng-repeat-start="item in items">
           <td ng-bind="getAvg('north')"></td>
       </tr>

        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
         .
         .
         .
        <tr class='group-footer-row' ng-repeat-end>....</tr>
</tbody>
```

You might have to do this inside another ng-repeat if the tbody sections are dynamic.  This will write out the first and last row one time.